# find multiple digits and a colon within a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find any string of digits followed by a colon.
Here is an example string:

```
var str = "  234:  all kinds of code";
```

Here is what I tried:

```
str.search(/^\d+:$/);
```

and that returns a -1 so it is not finding the digits followed by the colon.

I tried this and it returned 0:

```
/^.+\d+:.+$/
```

Comment: You should play with an online too like regex101 to work out your regexps.

Comment: Did `/^.+\d+:.+$/` not find anything ? I don't understand the question. Show the code you tried.

Comment: str.search(/^.+\d+:.+$/);
returns 0
it's cool - I know what I was doing wrong now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is only successful when the string to search *begins* and *ends* with digits followed by colon. Try this:

```
str.search(/\d+:/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `^` (matches only beginning of string, but your number is somewhere in the middle) and the `$` (matches only end of string, but there is text after the colon) from your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Use this website to verify your reg exs.  I use it all the time

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Drop your ^ and $ or place wildcards around your "\d+:"